# Delete file / directory in php?

Tags: php, file, unlink, rmdir

I am building a php file explorer. I've done the part of navigating between folders, opening files. Now giving continuity I am doing the part of deleting a file or directory.
However when using `unlink` he does not delete the file.

I've used:

```
unlink ('files/namefile.jpg')

unlink ('/var/www/html/project/files/namefile.jpg');
```

In the case of the directory I also tried with `rmdir`.

Can someone help me? I already researched in other posts, tried but nothing solved.

Comment: You should have a warning or error somewhere, these commands should work. PHP-user must have the "write" permission on the folder. Check also if all file handlers to the file you want to delete are properly closed.

Comment: It might not have permission to delete files in that folder.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to delete. They are also closed correctly. Close right after reading.

Comment: The entire folder has permission.